# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I have been starting off with some JDBC a few days ago as of 2019/3. And there was this error occurring when I try to comply the code below in my eclipse IDE.

I actually did some research before this and I have tried:-

-Adding external libraries from the project menu

-Reinstalling and trying out different ides(thinking it was just eclipse but turns out its something about my system)

-reinstalled both jdk and the jdbc connector

and still, the problem persists.

```java
import java.sql.*;
public class Driver{
    public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception {

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/main";
        String uName = "Ng Jun Han";
        String pW = "password";
        String query = "SELECT first FROM students WHERE id = 1";


        Class.forName("com.sql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uName, pW);
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(query);

        rs.next();
        String name = rs.getString("first");
        System.out.print(name);

        st.close();
        con.close();
    }
}
```

[This is how my project directory looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3Mp0.png)

My biggest concern regarding the topic is about something wrong I did with the installation methods. Mainly because there are not much up-to-date resources to follow.If so, does anyone know the CORRECT way of fixing it?(the driver jar file is located at C:\Program Files\MySQL , and i c/p-ed it into my the libraries file in my project directory) Thanks for helping:)

Comment: are you trying to get access different package db?

Comment: Could you include a stack trace with the question, this would help in analysing the issue.

Comment: Can you describe more about how you installed jdbc driver? May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434213/adding-jdbc-driver-to-classpath) will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this class name :

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
```

Refer to the official [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html)

Comment: Nice share, but i got this instead
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, I confirm you should use `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` instead, because the other one is deprecated now, or you can refer to a more up to date documentation : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52344453/loading-class-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-is-deprecated-message . Did some more research and fixed it. Many thanks.